# Startup screen toggle button [Visual Basic]

Tags: winforms, toggle

So, I'm working on a program in Visual Basic (2010) and I have a startup window with some quick buttons and stuff.
I want to have a checkbutton that can determine wether or not the startup screen will be displayed next time the application starts.

Anyone that can help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using settings (Right click your project in the Solution Explorer and go to "Properties", there'll be a tab called "Settings") and create a bool for "showStartup" then use the following code:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.showStartup)
{
    startupForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

As for working with a checkbox, you can use the "CheckedChanged" event and use:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.showStartup = showOnStartup.Checked;
```